# Android Accessibility: ActionMode actionBar items not read instead underlying action bar items are read

Tags: android, accessibility

When I select items in my list the contextual action bar appears. This bar has a number of action items that will be applicable to the selected items from the list.

When i turn on TalkBack and navigate to this contextual action bar, the focus appears to be on the contextual action bar but TalkBack actually reads out the items on the original actionBar (i presume this is underneath the contextual action bar).

How can i get talkback to only navigate through the contextual action bar items and never read out the actionBar items when the contextual action bar is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get a handle on the underlying toolbar and set it to invisible. Showing and hiding the support actionbar will not work as the content will slide up under the action mode bar.